# Writing code without curly braces

Tags: ide, indentation, code-formatting, curly-braces

I think curly braces are entirely redundant. Indentation alone should be enough to define codeblocks. Is there a way to set up Visual Studio or a different IDE so that indentation simply implies a curly brace? Of course, spaces or space-like characters should be disallowed from starting a new line then, because they may look like an indentation.

EDIT:
To make it clear, I want this

```
if (flag)  
    foo();  
    bar();
```

to be interpreted like this

```
if (flag) 
{   
    foo();  
    bar();  
}
```

because I want indentations to imply curly braces.

This

```
if (flag)  
    foo();  
bar();
```

should be interpreted as this

```
if (flag) 
{   
    foo();
}  
bar();
```

And this

```
if (flag)  
foo();
```

should throw a compiler error.

Curly braces would still be useful for when you don't want to start a new line (and for declaring enums and stuff), so I guess they're not *entirely* redundant. But they would be used very rarely.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong. Curly braces are needed to hold one block together without going back one level. If-clauses are onle one liners if you use no curly braces.

Comment: I know that. But it doesn't have to be that way. I asked for a way to make indentations IMPLY curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces, whether or not they are redundant are good visual indicators of code blocks. I don't see the need to remove them. When you have to scan thousands of lines of code, having visual helpers like braces (especially on new lines) and semi-colons are absolutely necessary in my opinion.